# How to return User already exist and User successfully created?

Tags: sequelize.js

This is my code how can return User Exist and not Exist.? Thank oyu

```
exports.create=(req, res)=>{
let registration=req.body.email;
User.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        email: registration
    }

}).spread((user,created)=>{
    console.log(user.get({
        plain: true
    }))
})
console.log(created)
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.create=(req, res)=>{
let registration=req.body.email;
User.findOrCreate({
   where: {
      email: registration
 }

}).spread((user,created)=>{
   if (created){
      res.send({ message: "user Created Successfully" });
   }
   else {
     res.send({ message: "user Already exists" });
   }
})
   console.log(created)
};
```

For further details read this docs [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html)